# USB charging in host mode

Tags: charging, usb-host-mode, usb-peripherals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using an OTG cable while charging](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34227/using-an-otg-cable-while-charging)

Recent versions of Android allow USB to operate in host mode.  But is it possible for them to be powered/charged via that same USB port while operating in host mode?

Comment: This was actually discussed on the [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange site](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34741/can-an-android-tablet-serve-as-usb-host-and-be-charged-simultaneously-through-a).

Comment: See also this answer here: [Using an OTG cable while charging](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34227/using-an-otg-cable-while-charging)

Answer (score 0):

There is only one USB port for USB OTG (which not supports USB hubs if I remember well) **AND** charging the phone. So you will have to make a choice. To my mind this is the main problem with USB charging. Phones are used to having a unique port and you have to choose what you want to do with this only port.