# Using an OTG cable while charging

Tags: charging, usb-host-mode

Most Android devices have a single port for both connecting to the computer (USB) and charging. I have to use this OTG small cable to transfer data, but also to use a real keyboard. However, when I connect the keyboard, I cannot recharge my device while I work. Since they both use the same port, is there a way to split an OTG cable to introduce power on it, but keep the existing port so I can connect a keyboard ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [USB charging in host mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28745/usb-charging-in-host-mode)

Comment: The linked answer has a VC with this as dupe already. Loop...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, at least technically.  What you need is a cable called a OTG host cable with power, which is a double-female cable with a male micro, a female micro (which only has the power and ground connected, no data), and a female A, like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009YPYORM).

Additionally, you also need software support.  I know an appropriate kernel patch is available for CM10 on the Nexus 7 ([here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130102101225/http://mehrvarz.github.com/)), but I don't know about any other devices.

Comment: Kali Linux's [NetHunter](https://www.kali.org/kali-linux-nethunter/) project has support for this in its kernel and runs on Nexus 5, 6, 7, 9 & 10 devices and the OnePlus One.

Comment: Links to code are dead, but I managed to find [two](https://github.com/faux123/Nexus-grouper/commits/lp_rel/drivers/usb) possible [versions](https://github.com/mehrvarz/android_kernel_asus_grouper/commits/cm-10.1/drivers/usb/otg) of what it could have been. Idk if nowadays this support comes out of the box, but I think that all the device specific adjustments should go in the relative [Host Controller Driver](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/usb/host/ehci-tegra.c) if any.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible, some phones support Battery Charging Specification 1.2 and can utilize [USB ACA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Accessory_charging_adaptors_.28ACA.29) (Accessory charging adaptor) which support OTG + Charging at the same time. (the Acasis H027 is one such adaptor)

My phone (Motorola Moto G XT1032) is not able to auto-detect such an adaptor out of the box, but after [modifying the kernel](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/otg-charging-using-usb-aca-accessory-t3431856/post68023045#post68023045), I was able to charge it and use USB Flash Drive + USB Ethernet at the same time.

Comment: Is there a way to tell what devices can do this? I tried Lava SimulCharge on Galaxy Tab A 7" with no luck, my Nexus 5X doesn't work either.

Comment: Excellent @Tal Alone. Awesome that you posted this here too. Madushan as he stated you have to modify the android kernel code to make it possible. Follow his link.